# how do you configure tether for popups with Zurb Foundation for Apps?

Tags: popup, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps, tether

I'd like to use popup functionality from Zurb Foundation for Apps ([Zurb's popup documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/popup)) which uses Tether ([Tether on GitHub](http://github.hubspot.com/tether/#usage)).  I've tried using the configuration as found on GitHub:

```
            new Tether({
                element: "yellowBox",
                target: "greenBox",
                attachment: 'bottom left',
                targetAttachment: 'top left'
            });
```

I'm running this in my Angular JS directive.  However, I get a JavaScript error in tether.min.js (Error: t is null).  That error message is not very helpful.

Zurb's documentation does not indicate how to configure popup.  I want the popup to happen to the right of the element that was clicked to open the popup.

Thanks for your help.